# How to determine region size automatically generated by g1gc?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot, g1gc

Documentation says that:

> Upon startup, the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) sets the region size

How could I determine what size was chosen for g1gc regions at the startup? How to get notification when it is changed during runtime?

I had tried to log gc info with `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` but it contains no information about region size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region size information can be printed with the `-XX:G1PrintRegionLivenessInfo` flag which must be used in conjunction with the `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions` flag (well, at least used to, not sure about the latest JVMs).

See also [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/understanding-g1-gc-logs) in the Oracle blog and [this very insightful article](http://product.hubspot.com/blog/g1gc-fundamentals-lessons-from-taming-garbage-collection) from Hubspot (simply search for "Min Heap Size").